# Editor in Spyder seems to be skipping lines of code in a function definition

Tags: python, function, editor, spyder

For some reason this function skips some of the lines of code. Some lines of code written inside in the function in a cell in Spyder (ver5.3.0) Editor window do not run, but the others run fine. When I run the same lines from the IPython console they work perfectly, but not when I run the cell from the editor window.
The 1st 3/4 of the code runs perfectly and the last two blocks of code (which creates the Strts_Working and Strts_Tramming) just don't want to run from the editor window. I have to manually cut and paste then to the console to create the data frames to get them to run.

I've checked the indenting, deleted the empty lines, changed order of the code blocks etc, but the results remain the same.

Here's the code:

```
def Power_State(PwrOff_thresh=20):

    global df, Strts_PwrOff, Strts_Standby, Strts_Wait, Strts_AllIdle, Strts_AllLoaded

    df['Tram_State']=np.nan
    df.loc[ ((df.Tram == 1) | (df.Tram == -1) | (df.TramOther == 1)) & (df.PumpI_State != 0), 'Tram_State']  =  1
    df.loc[ df.Tram_State != 1, 'Tram_State'] = 0
   
    # PwrOff
    df['Power_State']=np.nan
    df.loc[ (df.dT > PwrOff_thresh), 'Power_State'] = 0
    # Standby
    df.loc[ ((df.Power_State != 0) & (df.Pump_State == 0) & (df.Fan_State == 0) &
         (df.Conv_State == 0) & (df.Cut_State == 0) ),  'Power_State'] = 1
    # Waiting
    df.loc[ ((df.Power_State != 0) & (df.Power_State != 1) & (df.Pump_State > 0) & (df.Fan_State == 0) & (df.Conv_State == 0) &
         (df.Cut_State == 0) & (df.Tram_State == 0) ),  'Power_State'] = 2
    # Working
    df.loc[ ((df.Power_State != 0) & (df.Power_State != 1) & (df.Power_State != 2) & ((df.Pump_State >= 1) | (df.Fan_State >= 1) |
         (df.Conv_State >= 1) | (df.Cut_State >= 1) | (df.Tram_State != 0) )),  'Power_State'] = 3

    # Create Stop Start tables
    Strts_PwrOff = pd.DataFrame([])
    Strts_PwrOff['strt_time'] = df.index[(df.Power_State.shift(1) > 0) & (df.Power_State == 0)]
    Strts_PwrOff['stop_time'] = df.index[(df.Power_State.shift(1) == 0) & (df.Power_State > 0)]
    Strts_PwrOff['pwrOff_time'] = (Strts_PwrOff['stop_time'] - Strts_PwrOff['strt_time'])/pd.Timedelta(seconds=1)
    Strts_PwrOff.loc[:,'time_between_waits'] = (Strts_PwrOff.loc[:,'strt_time'].shift(-1) - Strts_PwrOff.loc[:,'stop_time'])/pd.Timedelta(seconds=1)

    Strts_Wait = pd.DataFrame([])
    Strts_Wait['strt_time'] = df.index[(df.Power_State.shift(1) != 2) & (df.Power_State == 2)]
    Strts_Wait['stop_time'] = df.index[(df.Power_State.shift(1) == 2) & (df.Power_State != 2)]
    Strts_Wait['pumpOn_time'] = (Strts_Wait['stop_time'] - Strts_Wait['strt_time'])/pd.Timedelta(seconds=1)
    Strts_Wait.loc[:,'time_between_pumpons'] = (Strts_Wait.loc[:,'strt_time'].shift(-1) - Strts_Wait.loc[:,'stop_time'])/pd.Timedelta(seconds=1)

    Strts_Working = pd.DataFrame([])
    Strts_Working['strt_time'] = df.index[(df.Power_State.shift(1) != 3) & (df.Power_State == 3)]
    Strts_Working['stop_time'] = df.index[(df.Power_State.shift(1) == 3) & (df.Power_State != 3)]
    Strts_Working['Strts_Working'] = (Strts_Working['stop_time'] - Strts_Working['strt_time'])/pd.Timedelta(seconds=1)
    Strts_Working.loc[:,'time_between_allidles'] = (Strts_Working.loc[:,'strt_time'].shift(-1) - Strts_Working.loc[:,'stop_time'])/pd.Timedelta(seconds=1)

    Strts_Tramming = pd.DataFrame([])
    Strts_Tramming['strt_time'] = df.index[ (df.Tram_State.shift(1)==0) & (df.Tram_State==1)]
    Strts_Tramming['stop_time'] = df.index[ (df.Tram_State.shift(1)==1) & (df.Tram_State==0)]
    Strts_Tramming['run_time'] = (Strts_Tramming['stop_time'] - Strts_Tramming['strt_time'])/pd.Timedelta(seconds=1)
    Strts_Tramming.loc[:,'time_between_runs'] = (Strts_Tramming.loc[:,'strt_time'].shift(-1) - Strts_Tramming.loc[:,'stop_time'])/pd.Timedelta(seconds=1)

    return

Power_State()
```

Comment: (*Spyder maintainer here*) I see that you're using global variables in your function. For those to work in Spyder, you need to go to the menu `Run > Configuration per file` and enable the option called `Run in console's namespace instead of an empty one`.

Comment: Thanks Carlos. This did not help though. The Strts_Working and  Strts_Tramming blocks at the end still do not run as part of the function.

Comment: I don't know what could be happening then, sorry.

Answer (score 2):

I found the issue. (Face plant). Carlos you were correct, the blocks which did not run were because they were not set as global variables... I added to and edited the code, and when doing so forget to update the global variables.

Thanks you for the assistance. :)

Comment: Great! Glad to know you were finally able to solve your problem.